# Error parsing string in C " left operand must be l-value"

Tags: c, string

I am faced with the need to pull out the information in a string of the format "blah.bleh.bloh" in ANSI C.  Normally I would use strok() to accomplish this, but since I am getting this string via strtok, and strtok is not thread-safe, I cannot use this option.

I have written a function to manually parse the string.  Here is a snippit:

```
for(charIndex=0; charIndex < (char)strlen(theString); charIndex++)
{
    if(theString[charIndex] == '.')
    {
        theString[charIndex] = '\0';
        osi_string_copy_n(Info[currentInfoIndex], 1024, theString, charIndex + 1 );
        currentInfoIndex++;
        theString = &theString[charIndex + 1];
    }
    charIndex++;
}
```

As you can see, I try to find the first occurrence of '.' and make note of the index of the character.  Then I convert the '.' to a null char and copy the first string to an array.

Then I want to change the pointer to start just after where the delimiter was found, essentially giving me a new shorter string.

Unfortunately I am getting an error on the line:

```
theString = &theString[charIndex + 1];
```

The error is:

```
error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
```

Why am I not allowed to move the pointer like this?  Is my method flawed?  Perhaps someone has a better idea for me to parse this string.

EDIT:  In response to the comments, the declaration for theString is:

```
char theString[1024] = {0};
```

Also, I am guaranteed that theString will never be more than 1024 characters.

Comment: Let us know how `theString` is declared.

Comment: You should also take a look at some of the other string functions, like strspn and strcspn.

Comment: Unrelated, but why "(char)strlen(theString)"? Do you want this function to be unable to deal with strings longer than 128 characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the assumption that you defined theString as an array, try defining it as a pointer.  When you declare a char variable as an array, you cannot later change its address.

I am assuming you have a declaration similar to

```
char theString[100];
```

The easiest solution is to leave that declaration alone, and add another one:

```
char *str = theString;
```

and then use `str` everywhere that you currently use `theString`.

Comment: If I declare theString as a pointer, won't I then have to malloc space for it?  Part of the reason I was declaring it with defined space is so that I wouldn't have to worry about deallocating the memory in a complicated series of if then else statements later.

Comment: That's why I recommended leaving the allocation alone and then defining a pointer to reference the array.  The pointer you can change at will.

Comment: Ahh, I understand, now.  This would be a good solution to my problem. However, I actually ended up using an internally developed version of strtok that is thread-safe.  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`strtok_r`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strtok.html) which is available on most platforms and is reentrant. This means that it does not hold internal state, and you can call it from nested loops with no trouble.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one true C way, the use of pointers, tight loops and arcane commands :-).

The `getNext()` function below will allow you to return all the components in order, followed by a NULL sentinel. You need to provide a big enough buffer to store the components. I've also included my test program so you can check it (and add more unit test cases if you wish).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getNext (char *pStr, char *pComp) {
    /* Special for '.' at string end. */
    if ((*pStr == '.') && (*(pStr+1) == '\0')) {
        *pComp = '\0';
        return pStr + 1;
    }

    /* Check if no components left. */
    if (*pStr == '\0')
        return NULL;

    /* Transfer component one character at a time. */
    while ((*pStr != '\0') && (*pStr != '.'))
        *pComp++ = *pStr++;
    *pComp = '\0';

    /* Skip '.' at end, if there, but not at end of string. */
    if ((*pStr == '.') && (*(pStr+1) != '\0'))
        pStr++;

    // Return location of next component.
    return pStr;
}

int main (int argCount, char *argVal[]) {
    int argNum;
    int compNum;
    char *newStr;
    char *strPtr;

    if (argCount < 2) {
        printf ("Usage: components <string to componentize>...\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (argNum = 1; argNum < argCount; argNum++) {
        if ((newStr = malloc (strlen (argVal[1]) + 1)) == NULL) {
            printf ("Out of memory for '%s'.", argVal[argNum]);
        } else {
            printf ("Input string is '%s'.\n", argVal[argNum]);
            compNum = 0;
            strPtr = getNext (argVal[argNum],newStr);
            while (strPtr != NULL) {
                printf ("   Component [%3d] is '%s'.\n", ++compNum, newStr);
                strPtr = getNext (strPtr,newStr);
            }
            free (newStr);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output:

```
[fury]> components your.test.string .dot.at.start at.end. .both. no_dots ''
Input string is 'your.test.string'.
    Component [  1] is 'your'.
    Component [  2] is 'test'.
    Component [  3] is 'string'.
Input string is '.dot.at.start'.
    Component [  1] is ''.
    Component [  2] is 'dot'.
    Component [  3] is 'at'.
    Component [  4] is 'start'.
Input string is 'at.end.'.
    Component [  1] is 'at'.
    Component [  2] is 'end'.
    Component [  3] is ''.
Input string is '.both.'.
    Component [  1] is ''.
    Component [  2] is 'both'.
    Component [  3] is ''.
Input string is 'no_dots'.
    Component [  1] is 'no_dots'.
Input string is ''.
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable "theString" must be a pointer and not an array type.

Answer (score 0):

The line `theString = &theString[charIndex + 1];` should have never existed in the first place. Even if this line don't give error and run properly, `theString[charIndex]` will not be the next adjacent character which you expect, as `theString` is moved.

My recommendation, with nearly minimal code change:

```
for(charIndex=0; charIndex < strlen(theString); charIndex++)
{
    if(theString[charIndex] == '.')
    {
        theString[charIndex] = '\0';
        osi_string_copy_n(Info[currentInfoIndex], 1024, theString + subStrStart, charIndex + 1 - subStrStart);
        currentInfoIndex++;
        subStrStart = charIndex + 1;
    }
    charIndex++;
}
```

I am not sure what does your `osi_string_copy_n` do, so that line is just a guess from your original code. But if you are copying away the substrings to another place, with the substring length specified in the function parameter, then there should be no need to null the end of substring?

**Edit:**
I found your code has two `charIndex++`. Is `theString` double byte string? If it's so, maybe it is more proper to use `wchar_t`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a non-ancient `libc`, you have `strtok_r`, which is a re-entrant variant of `strtok`.

```
char *saveptr;
char *str;
for (str = strtok_r(theString, ".", &saveptr);
        str;
        str = strtok_r(NULL, ".", &saveptr)
    )
{
    printf("got: '%s'\n", str);
}
```

This is guaranteed not to clobber any state `strtok` keeps around, or any state other `strtok_r` calls keep (assuming they don't share your `saveptr`).

Comment: Good answer. Isn't the second param of strtok_r() supposed to be a string?

Comment: You're right, it's supposed to be a string of delimiters and not just a character.  I'll fix that...